# Use another database for test

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

I have a program who use oracle.
I would like to do some test about the query who are done.
Db test is HSQLDB.

```
public class UserDAODataAccess {
    private Connection connection;

    private void getConnection() throws MMException {
        connection = AutoExternalServices.getDatabase().newConnection();
    }


    List<User> getUser(){
        getConnection();
        ...
    }
}
```

In test is it possible to bypass the current getConnection and obtain a connection for another db?

Comment: Do you do pure JDBC in your application? or do you use a persistence framework? If so which one?

Comment: What is the code of AutoExternalServices.getDatabase() then?

Comment: setting of connection

Comment: This is *the exact entire point* of dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Having difficulties replacing the `Connection` from your `AutoExternalServices` with a test connection, should ring your alarm bells. Usually such difficulties come from a bad/suboptimal design.

In your case, if you can, I'd suggest you provide the `Connection` as a constructor argument and remove the `getConnection()` method. This would make it easy to swap the `Connection` for your tests.

As for bypassing the `getConnection()`, there's all sorts 'hacks' to do this, including a switch on a system property, overriding the method in a special test class, ...

But I **wouldn't recommend any of them** ...